# can't compile ffmpeg on Solaris 10 sparc

Tags: ffmpeg, solaris, sparc

Has anyone compiled ffmpeg 0.6.1 for Solaris 10 sparc? I'm getting the following errors:

```
    uname -a
SunOS SERVERNAME 5.10 Generic_118833-36 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

bwddmadm@bwddmliv>/export/home/USERID/ffmpeg-0.6.1/configure --prefix=/export/home/USERID/ffmpegX --extra-cflags="-fPIC" --disable-mmx --disable-protocol=udp --disable-encoder=nellymoser
Broken shell detected.  Trying alternatives.
Trying shell bash
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
Unknown C compiler gcc
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
install prefix            /export/home/USERID/ffmpegX
source path               /export/home/USERID/ffmpeg-0.6.1
C compiler                gcc
.align is power-of-two    no
ARCH                      sparc (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     no
VIS enabled               yes
gprof enabled             no
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
new filter support        no
filters using lavformat   no
network support           yes
threading support         no
SDL support               no
Sun medialib support      no
AVISynth enabled          no
libdc1394 support         no
libdirac enabled          no
libfaac enabled           no
libfaad enabled           no
libfaad dlopened          no
libgsm enabled            no
libmp3lame enabled        no
libnut enabled            no
libopencore-amrnb support no
libopencore-amrwb support no
libopenjpeg enabled       no
librtmp enabled           no
libschroedinger enabled   no
libspeex enabled          no
libtheora enabled         no
libvorbis enabled         no
libvpx enabled            no
libx264 enabled           no
libxvid enabled           no
zlib enabled              no
bzlib enabled             no

Enabled decoders:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled encoders:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled hwaccels:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled parsers:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled demuxers:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled muxers:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled protocols:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled filters:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled bsfs:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled indevs:
pr:  -- empty file

Enabled outdevs:
pr:  -- empty file

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
Creating config.mak and config.h...
bwddmadm@bwddmliv> gmake
/export/home/USERID/ffmpeg-0.6.1/version.sh: syntax error at line 4: `revision=$' unexpected
CC      libavdevice/alldevices.o
libavdevice/alldevices.c: In function `avdevice_register_all':
libavdevice/alldevices.c:42: error: `CONFIG_ALSA_OUTDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:42: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
libavdevice/alldevices.c:42: error: for each function it appears in.)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:42: error: `CONFIG_ALSA_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:43: error: `CONFIG_AUDIO_BEOS_OUTDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:43: error: `CONFIG_AUDIO_BEOS_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:44: error: `CONFIG_BKTR_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:45: error: `CONFIG_DV1394_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:46: error: `CONFIG_JACK_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:47: error: `CONFIG_OSS_OUTDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:47: error: `CONFIG_OSS_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:48: error: `CONFIG_V4L2_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:49: error: `CONFIG_V4L_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:50: error: `CONFIG_VFWCAP_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:51: error: `CONFIG_X11_GRAB_DEVICE_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
libavdevice/alldevices.c:54: error: `CONFIG_LIBDC1394_INDEV' undeclared (first use in this function)
gmake: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
bwddmadm@bwddmliv> exit

script done on Fri Jan 14 11:34:05 2011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Solaris `/usr/bin/grep` does not support the -q flag](http://bugs.opensolaris.org/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4843344), it looks like you'll need to set your path to either find `GNU grep` or the POSIX-compliant `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` as the grep command.   Google can also find a couple patches to ffmpeg that people have written to solve this.

The ffmpeg authors [know](http://roundup.ffmpeg.org/issue156) of this [problem](https://roundup.ffmpeg.org/issue1217), but refuse to change their configure script, since they rely on POSIX-compliance.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this out today. I can't find the patches you mention, could you provide a link please?

Comment: Hi, I tried creating an alias for grep via: alias='/usr/xpg4/bin/grep' then I re did the configure part and recieved the same errors.

Comment: Scripts like configure run in a new shell process and won't pick up aliases from your current shell process - you'd have to change your path.   The patches I was referring to were at links such as https://trac.handbrake.fr/browser/trunk/contrib/patch-ffmpeg-solaris.patch?rev=1531

Comment: Thanks, this patch is three years old, I don't have matching lines in the current version of ffmpeg which I downloaded. I googled and can't find a patch for this version 0.6.1. I've got past a lot of the problems (see my conversation with ShiDoiSi below). The configure works fine, I'm stuck at the 'make' part. Do you have ffmpeg installed? Thanks again for all your advice.

Comment: No, I've never built or used ffmpeg, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

1.- Make sure gcc is installed

```
install gcc if needed
# pkg search gcc
# pkg install pkg:/developer/gcc-45@4.5.2-0.175.1.0.0.24.0
```

2.- Make sure yams is installed

```
install yams if needed
download from http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz
unzip, untar in local dir
#./configure
#make install
add the path
# PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

3.- Make sure GNU Make is installed

```
Installed if required
# pkg search gnu make
# pkg install pkg:/developer/build/gnu-make@3.82-0.175.1.0.0.24.0
```

4.- Make sure that it picks up the correct grep

```
e.g. by aliasing grep to /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep if you have the Sun Freeware package installed
```

5.- Download source code : http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-1.0.tar.gz

```
a.- unzip, untar in local dir
b.- edit configure
    1.- replace awk by nawk
    2.- follow the patch configuration from https://trac.handbrake.fr/browser/trunk/contrib/patch-ffmpeg-solaris.patch?rev=1531
        Some details about the reasons here : http://www.techques.com/question/1-4690966/can't-compile-ffmpeg-on-Solaris-10-sparc
        Be careful the line numbers are not valid for version 1.0
        place the modifications suggested accordingly 
c.- #./configure
d.- # gmake
```

Noël Jaffré

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the build script is expecting to find the GNU versions of helpers like grep. Make sure that it picks up the correct ones, e.g. by aliasing grep to `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep` if you have [the Sun Freeware package](http://www.sun.com/software/solaris/freeware/) installed.

Comment: I tried this by creating an alias: alias grep='/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep' and then re did the configure, I still get the errors above. Anything else you suggest I try? Thanks.

Comment: Hm, good question. then just symlink somewhere with name `grep`, and put the place at the front of the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll test this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well that got me a little further I think. I can't post it here due to lack of space. http://pastebin.com/Z5LdsbbX If you have any further advice that would be a great help, I appreciate what you've done so far. Thanks

Comment: Well, the next candidate seems to be awk -> gawk.

Comment: I don't have a gawk under /usr/sfw/bin, does it live somewhere else? which gawk returns nothing.

Comment: I've installed gawk from source, and symlinked awk to gawk as with grep. I'll test this out

Comment: Well, I don't get any warnings at configure time now, I still get the same errors mentioned above when I try to 'make' it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I managed to install it from source, and now I don't get any warnings at the configure stage. Thanks for that. The problem is at the make stage I still get the same errors listed above.

Comment: Uh, indeed, sorry, that doesn't help much. You could go through config.log and see if you spot anything fishy.

Comment: Okay, there's a problem with linking, as it is picking the system linker 'ld' instead of the GNU linker 'gld'; and the assembler (g)as, So just handle this one just like you handled (g)grep. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added ld and gas as per your advice, in the same way we did with grep.
I See things like: ld.so.1: cc1: fatal: libmpc.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)

and

ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to /tmp/ffconf.XXBna4re
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

http://pastebin.com/r1t55m8m

Comment: Well, now it's getting a bit tricky, since we are looking at configure...some error may just be the expected result of trying to configure. Any change in the "real" output of ./configure?

Comment: ShiDoiSi, many thanks for all the help so far, can you suggest any way forwards with this configure problem?

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours on this topic I finally installed ffmpeg 2.2.2 on Solaris 5.1 SPARC. Steps:

- Download tar source of latest version from
  http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html
- Extract the tar
- Grep should refer to GGREP - alias grep = /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep
- Use bash instead of sh -  1st row of configuration and version.sh
  files needs to be modified
- Use nawk instead of awk
- The config handles implicit-function-declaration warning as error.
  This might cause problem - I had to set it back to warning level as
  it caused an error regarding a missing reference (which was a
  standard library so it should not be a problem)
- Regarding the 4-6 points apply the following commands
- `sed 's/\/bin\/sh/\/bin\/bash/' configure > configure.mod`
- `sed 's/awk/nawk/' configure.mod > configure.mod2`
- `sed '/implicit-function-declaration/d' configure.mod2 > configure.mod3`
- `cp configure.mod3 configure`
- `sed 's/\/bin\/sh/\/bin\/bash/' version.sh > version.sh.mod`
- `cp version.sh.mod version.sh`
- Run configure
- configure --extra-cflags="-fpic" --disable-mmx
        --disable-protocol=udp --disable-encoder=nellymoser --disable-debug --arch=sparc --target-os=sunos
- gmake install
- start ffmpeg : ./ffmpeg